# prevent default on named anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a function to scroll smoothly to subsections of my page.

The code requires-

```
event.preventDefault();
```

-to prevent the page from jumping to the top when an anchor is clicked, but it also doesn't append the hashtag to the url which is used for seo.

This is the scroll function I'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.secondaryNav a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
         //calculate destination place
         var dest=0;
         scrolling = false;
         if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
              dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();

         }else{
              dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
         }
         //go to destination
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 2000,'easeInOutCubic',function() {
         });

     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preventDefault` will stop the hash from being added to the URL, but you can add it yourself.

```
location.hash = this.hash;
```

This will call `onhashchange` and scroll the browser to the hash, so make sure you call it after the scroll is done.

```
var hash = this.hash;
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 2000,'easeInOutCubic',function() {
    location.hash = hash;
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Sub7m/4/show/ (edit it at: http://jsfiddle.net/Sub7m/4/)

If your browser supports it, you can also use `history.replaceState({}, null, this.hash)` to add the hash to the URL without moving the browser or calling `onhashchange`.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Sub7m/5/show/ (edit it at: http://jsfiddle.net/Sub7m/5/)